# Winforms: Textcolor of RichTextBox text turns transparent after gettings focus

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I implemented a `dynamic RichTextBox` (it can increase its width based on the content). But when i previously entered some text and double-click it to change the string in in the text turns transparent.

From the moment I start adding text, the characters become visible again.

On double-click, I just do this:

```
myAnnotationTextBox.Show();
myAnnotationTextBox.Focus();
```

The code of my custom RichTextBox:

```
public class AlphaBlendTextBox : RichTextBox
{
    private const int _initialWidth = 100;

    public AlphaBlendTextBox(Font textBoxFont, Color theCurrentForeColor)
    {
        this.Font = textBoxFont;
        this.ForeColor = theCurrentForeColor;
        this.BackColor = Color.White;
        this.AutoSize = false;
        this.WordWrap = false;
        this.Multiline = true;
        this.Height = textBoxFont.Height;
        this.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBoxScrollBars.None;
        this.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        this.HideSelection = false;
    }

    protected override void OnContentsResized(ContentsResizedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnContentsResized(e);

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Text))
        {
            Width = _initialWidth;
        }
        else
        {
            Width = e.NewRectangle.Width;
            Height = e.NewRectangle.Height;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you call the thing 'AlphaBlendTextBox ' ? Transparency and TextBoxes of all kinds doesn't go together, really..

Comment: The code you posted does not duplicate the problem for us.

Comment: ok thx for letting me know, i thought it had something to do with selectioncolor or something